# Optimization - Algorithm for finding load set combination that returns the maximum Von Mises stress

Tags: optimization, complexity-theory, nonlinear-optimization, computation-theory

I recently stumbled upon an optimization problem while working on structural analysis. While I'm confident in my MATLAB skills as an aerospace engineer, I must admit my theoretical knowledge in optimization is not extensive. Here's the challenge I'm facing:

I have a structure loaded with `NU` unitary loads, each impacting the structure independently. This setup allows me to calculate stress components for each finite element. The stress components (`sigma_u_xx`, `sigma_u_yy`, and `sigma_u_xy`) for `NE` elements are represented as matrices:

```
sigma_u_xx = rand(NE,NU)
sigma_u_yy = rand(NE,NU)
sigma_u_xy = rand(NE,NU)
```

Based on the problem's linearity, scaling the unit loads by a factor `x` linearly affects the stress components. This means I can analyze a small set of unit loads (even a hundred is considered small) and combine them linearly to obtain stresses for real load cases. For each unit load, there are only two possible choices for the coefficient of linear combination (`x`):

For each element, I compute the resultant stress components as a linear combination of the unit loads:

```
for e = 1:NE
  sigma_tot_xx(e) = sigma_u_xx(e,:)*x
  sigma_tot_yy(e) = sigma_u_yy(e,:)*x
  sigma_tot_xy(e) = sigma_u_xy(e,:)*x
end
```

Then, for any `x`, I evaluate the Von Mises stress using the formula:

```
sigma_VM = sqrt(sigma_tot_xx.^2 + sigma_tot_yy.^2 - sigma_tot_xx.*sigma_tot_yy + 3.*sigma_tot_xy)
```

But here's where I'm struggling: finding the combination of `x` that maximizes the Von Mises stress for each element.

One approach is to generate every possible combination of `x` using a Cartesian product, evaluate the objective function sigma_VM, and save the maximum value. However, this brute-force method becomes impractical when `NU` exceeds 30 due to its complexity, which is O(2^NU), if I'm correct.

I'm wondering if this problem fits into a specific class of optimization problems, and if there are more efficient algorithms to solve it. And if such algorithms exist, do they converge to a global maximum?

Alternatively, is there a way to exclude some combinations a priori without testing them? I assume this is what optimization algorithms aim to do.

Perhaps it's easier to reason about just one element, as the results are extensible to any `NE`. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.
Even if I expressed some concepts in MATLAB, my question is more about theroy rather than coding. Any example in any programming language is welcome.

Comment: Just to be clear on the variables...  so the choice of coefficient is "per unit load" and there are just 2 choices, and those chosen coefficients are used across all elements and axes...correct?  So you have `NU * 2` variables in this problem if that is correct, and brute force would be `2^NU`, which is much more daunting

Comment: I think you are going to end up with a Quadratic Integer Program (QIP).  Poke around on the web...  there are several frameworks to express the problem and several solvers that can handle QIP.  Unsure about optimality guarantees, but that is a place to start.  You might also cross-post on the Operations Research site after a little more research.

Comment: Thank you @AirSquid. I think it is possible to transform my objective function (ignoring the sqrt) into a quadratic functional in the form x'*M*x, with M an NUxNU unsymmetric matrix. Do you know a specific website where to post this question?